# How to control the sum value of a random binary vector in R

Tags: r, vector

I am trying to create a vector of only `0`s and `1`s. I know how to do this, however, I would like to control the sum value as well ​as the length of the vector. How could I do this?

Answer (score 2):

The following creates a vector of length `len`, and then randomly select `n_sum` locations for which `1` is assigned.

```
len <- 10
n_sum <- 7

vec <- numeric(len)
vec[sample(1:len, n_sum, replace = FALSE)] <- 1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sum <- 100
length <- 121

my_vector <- c(rep(0,length - sum),rep(1,sum))

> length(q)
[1] 121

> sum(q)
[1] 100
```